# Restoring nested recyclerview state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewstate

....
Hello, everyone.
I am developing an application where there is a nested recyclerviews like play store:

[image]

When you open one item a new fragment is opened. And when you press back button child recyclerview state (scroll positions, ...) is restored. How do they achieve that?

In my case ChildRecyclerviews are not restoring their state?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Shared Preferences` for that. When an item is clicked I save its position, and when the list is restored, I go back to that position.

the code inside the main fragment:

```
    SharedPreferences XYsharedPreferences; // global variable

    ...

    final ListView listView = view.findViewById (R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter (rowsAdapter); // created before...
    listView.setOnItemClickListener ((parent, view, position, id) -> {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = XYsharedPreferences.edit ();
        editor.putInt ("row", position);
        editor.apply ();

        ...

    });

    XYsharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences ("xyRows", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (XYsharedPreferences != null){
        final int position = XYsharedPreferences.getInt ("row", 0);
        listView.setSelection (position);
    }
```